# Why is `as Date` required for `timeIntervalSince()` with two `NSDate` objects?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have an `NSManagedObject` object with:

```
@NSManaged public var timestamp: NSDate
```

I needed the time interval between two of these, so I implemented:

```
let interval = next.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(current.timestamp)
```

Why does this result in the following error?

```
'NSDate' is not implicitly convertible to 'Date'; did you mean to use
'as' to explicitly convert?
```

I'm surprised because both `next` and `current` are of type `NSDate`, and `timeIntervalSince()` is an `NSDate` method.

It's easily fixed by following the suggestion in the error, but I'd like to understand what going on here:

```
let interval = next.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(current.timestamp as Date)
```

In case it matters, this is on Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [NSDate Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate):

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Date
>   structure, which bridges to the NSDate class. The Date value type
>   offers the same functionality as the NSDate reference type, and the
>   two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with
>   Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges
>   standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding
>   Foundation classes.

If you check `timeIntervalSince` method signature, it is `func timeIntervalSince(_ anotherDate: Date) -> TimeInterval`, note that `anotherDate` date type is `Date` (not `NSDate` anymore).

For more information about new value types, check [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md) of mutability and foundation value types, there is a bunch of new value types such as: NSData, NSMutableData -> *Data*, NSIndexPath -> *IndexPath*, NSNotification -> *Notification*...